# SAS e R executam o Merge de forma diferente

Tags: r, sas, merge

Qual a diferença entre a forma como o R e o SAS executam o merge?
O comando Merge do SAS retorna 205546 linhas já o do R retorna 207208 linhas.
Segue exemplo.

Estou trabalhando com o arquivo do IBGE disponível em:
ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/PNS/2013/microdados/pns_2013_microdados.zip

Serão utilizadas as bases DOMPNS2013.txt e PESPNS2013.txt

SAS:
1) Atribuição das variáveis: execute os arquivos "input DOMPNS2013" e "input PESPNS2013"
2) Seleção de um valor de interesse e Merge:

```
data dompns2013v3;  
set dompns2013;  
if V0015 = 1;  
run;  
/*NOTE: There were 81187 observations read from the data set WORK.DOMPNS2013.
NOTE: The data set WORK.DOMPNS2013V2 has 64348 observations and 20 variables.*/  

data arq.dompes2013v3;  
merge dompns2013v3 pespns2013;   
by v0001 v0024 upa_pns v0006;  
run;  
/*NOTE: There were 64348 observations read from the data set WORK.DOMPNS2013V2.
NOTE: There were 205546 observations read from the data set WORK.PESPNS2013.
NOTE: The data set ARQ.DOMPES2013V2 has 205546 observations and 388 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):*/
```

#

R:
1) atribuição das variáveis:

```
d2013 = read.fwf(file='DOMPNS2013.txt',widths=c(2,8,7,4,2,6,1,1))  

names(d2013) = c("v0001","v0024","upa_pns","v0006","v0015","skip1","v0026","v0031")  

d2013 = subset(d2013,select=c("v0001","v0024","upa_pns","v0006","v0015","v0026","v0031"))  

p2013 = read.fwf(file='PESPNS2013.txt',widths=c(2,8,7,4,1,2,2,2,1,8,3))  

names(p2013)=c("v0001","v0024","upa_pns","v0006","v0025","skip1","c00301","c004","c006","skip2","c008")  

p2013=subset(p2013,select=c("v0001","v0024","upa_pns","v0006","v0025","c00301","c004","c006","c008"))
```

2) Seleção de um valor de interesse e Merge:

```
dim(d2013)  
[1] 81187     7  

d2013 = subset(d2013, d2013$v0015 == 1)  
dim(d2013)  
[1] 64348     7  

dim(p2013)  
[1] 205546      9  

dpmerge = merge( p2013,d2013,by=c("v0001","v0024","upa_pns","v0006"))  
dim(dpmerge)  
[1] 207208     12
```

Comment: Henrique, me parece que o SAS está removendo os **registros duplicados** do `DOMPNS` antes de fazer o merge. Se você fizer `d2013 <- unique(d2013)` antes de fazer o merge no R, o número de observações será igual.

Answer (score 1):

O SAS está removendo os registros duplicados do DOMPNS antes de fazer o merge.

Se você fizer `d2013 <- unique(d2013)` antes de fazer o merge no R, o número de observações será igual.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Henrique! Não conheço como funcionao merge no R, mas no SAS sim. Para usar o merge no SAS você precisa ordenar previamente os dois datasets pela chave de cruzamento, pois caso aconteça de termos um valor de chave menor em valores posteriores, eles serão desprezados.

No seu caso, o seguinte código (colocado logo antes de se usar o merge) resolveria o problema;

`proc sort data dompns2013v3; by v0001 v0024 upa_pns v0006; run;
 proc sort data pespns2013; by v0001 v0024 upa_pns v0006; run;`

O que eu te recomendaria é usar o proc sql para cruzar tabelas. O merge é a opção mais eficiente para cruzamento, mas as tabelas precisam estar ordenadas. Usando o **proc sql**, por outro lado, você não precisa ordenar as bases, além do fato de que usar a linguagem SQL é algo mais versátil, pois você consegue usar em diversos bancos de dados. Como não sei a estrutura das tabelas que você está usando, não consigo te passar um código equivalente em SQL, mas você consegue achar na internet facilmente.

Algumas considerações/dicas que não se relacionam diretamente com a dúvida mas que podem vir a ser úteis:

-para filtrar registros, utilize a cláusula **WHERE** ao invés de if, pois é mais eficiente. No seu caso você troca este trecho de código (**if V0015 = 1;**) por este aqui (**where V0015 = 1;**);
- se existir a possibilidade de ter duplicidade de chaves e supondo também que você queira apenas os registros únicos, adicione a opção **nodupkey** no **proc sort** (após o código **data=base_entrada**). Lembrando que ele vai manter apenas o primeiro valor que a chave aparece na base; então, caso a ordem em que a chave apareça, e não apenas a chave em si, seja importante, você primeiro utiliza o **proc sort** sem a opção **nodupkey** (colocando na ordenação - **cláusula by** - as chaves e os critérios) e em seguida utiliza o **proc sort** com a opção **nodupkey** (colocando na **cláusula by** apenas a chave).